# How do I multiply a group of cells by a certain number, based on if they have a value in them or not

Tags: worksheet-function, google-spreadsheets

I want to have a cell (the K column, for allowance) multiply the number of days in it's row (the C-I columns, Sunday - Sat) only if they have a value, by 100.

For example, if Monday, Tues, Wed all have a number in them (no matter what the number is) and the rest of that week is blank, I want the allowance column to automatically say "300" because it will be 3 of the 7 days with a value x 100 each.

Then I want to be able to total all of that column in K15.

Right now I have hidden on a different part of the sheet, rows with "  =IF(ISNUMBER(C10), "100", "")     " but I can't SUM all of the 100s in those cells.

To clarify my goal in case that helps. We are allowed 100 miles total per day that we drive. If we go OVER 100 miles for that day, we get an allowance on the overage.

NOTE - I'm currently working in google sheets and not excel, if that makes a difference.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KblEp.png)

Answer (score 0):

Exclude zero: `=countif(C2:H2,">0")*100`
Include zero: `=countif(C2:H2,">=0")*100`

Nothing but a number will be =0 or >0 so no need to do any other tests.

##### Formulas

|  | H |
| --- | --- |
| **1** | **allowance** |
| **2** | =countif(C2:H2,">0")*100 |
| **3** | =countif(C3:H3,">0")*100 |
| **4** | =countif(C4:H4,">0")*100 |

##### Sample Output

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I | J | K |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** |  |  | **Sun** | **Mon** | **Tues** | **Thurs** | **Fri** | **Sat** |  |  | **allowance** |
| **2** |  |  | 42 | A | 7 | baba |  |  |  |  | 200 |
| **3** |  |  | John | Bob | Jerry | 1 | 2 | 3 |  |  | 300 |
| **4** |  |  | 1 | 3 | 66 | hmm | 0 | 7 |  |  | 400 |

Comment: This is EXACTLY what I needed, thank you so much!

Comment: That's great!  Please consider upvoting and accepting the answer.  See [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers).